# Rails ActiveRecord return an association with a limit query (No eager loading support)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently working with Rails 6. I have the following association

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, limit: 5
  has_many :all_items, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Item
  belong_to :category
end
```

Now, the `limit: 5` doesn't work since all the items are returned. I see from the documentation that `limit` will be ignored as mentioned in the following line:

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it
> will be ignored, returning all the associated objects:

The above can be found in the following documentation:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

So what to do in this case?

I'm using `jsonapi-serializer` and I want to return a Category item with only 5 items. There is no limit option when using `include:` so I wonder what is the best case scenario here. I thought about using the [ActiveRecord Preloader](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader) but since this is a private method I don't think that is the best idea.

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    categories = stock.categories

    binding.pry
    # ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(categories, :items, Struct.new(:items, :bind_values).new({limit: 5}, []))

    render json: CategorySerializer.new(stock.categories).serializable_hash,
      { how to include items with a limit here? }, status: 200
  end
```

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using manual sql query in where clause to get the result?

Comment: I don't understand from the question, do you want eager loading support or not?

Comment: @razvans eager loading is not supported. So how can I do ?